# Non-linear slerp animation with quaternion

Tags: math, animation, graphics, 3d

While the popular `slerp` formula for interpolating between 3D orientations is pretty cool and useful, it occurs to me that this is a linear animation.

Less complicated animation, such as simple tweening between floats, is easily altered to quadratic ease-in and ease-out, but the `slerp` formula is not so simple (its inventor Shoemake didn't even publish the formula's derivation upon his initial discovery).

So I'm using this:

```
template <typename T>
inline QuaternionT<T> QuaternionT<T>::Slerp(T t, const QuaternionT<T>& v1) const
{  
const T epsilon = 0.0005f;
T dot = Dot(v1);

if (dot > 1 - epsilon) {
    QuaternionT<T> result = v1 + (*this - v1).Scaled(t);
    result.Normalize();
    return result;
}

if (dot < 0)
    dot = 0;

if (dot > 1)
    dot = 1;

T theta0 = std::acos(dot);
T theta = theta0 * t;

QuaternionT<T> v2 = (v1 - Scaled(dot));
v2.Normalize();

QuaternionT<T> q = Scaled(std::cos(theta)) + v2.Scaled(std::sin(theta));
q.Normalize();
return q;
}
```

Does anyone know how to make this an easing interpolation based on `t` (which is the elapsed/duration)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the rate of change of `t` that controls the "ease" of the lerping, not the lerping itself. I assume that `T` is a scalar (like float/double).

AFAICT, you're trying to get an ease-in effect, but the path itself is a "straight" rotation between the start and end quaternions. Consequently, as long as `t` varies from 0 to 1, all you have to do is *vary the rate of change of t* to get your "easing interpolation".

I usually use the `3*t^2-2*t^3` formula for ease in/out. I'll leave a [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp) here, just in case.

(I feel like I'm missing something here. Let me know if this answered your question).

Comment: This formula you have is simple and interesting, but I cannot find it mentioned anywhere online. Where did you get it? I'd like to know other simple Ease formulas that only require `t` and not knowledge of the start or end points. The ease in/out formula I've seen everywhere else is quite a bit different. For example here: http://gizma.com/easing/

Comment: actually I just did a quick spreadsheet to see the results of this formula and it looks like an ease in only, but does not ease out. that is the rate of change in the second half of the tweening is still faster than a linear, rather than slower as expected with an ease out.

Comment: See [this](http://webstaff.itn.liu.se/~stegu/TNM022-2005/perlinnoiselinks/perlin-noise-math-faq.html) (search for "ease curve").